# How to specify the way a code snippet is marked up?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdoc

### Goal

For documentation purposes I would like to export a C++ code snippet from QtCreator as an HTML file and then use CSS to highlight its syntax, for example like that:

[image: syntax highlighted code]

Since QtCreator does not have an export option, I am using [`QDoc`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoc-index.html) to achieve that.

As per documentation, I use [`\quotefile`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/07-0-qdoc-commands-includingexternalcode.html#quotefile) in a `qdoc`-file in my project to turn the source code from `main.cpp` into an HTML:

```
/*!
    \page index
    \quotefile main.cpp
 */
```

Running `qdoc` produces an `index.html` and when I open it, there is indeed the marked-up content of `main.cpp`.

**Note:** To demonstrate the issue I am using the code from the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/07-0-qdoc-commands-includingexternalcode.html#quotefile):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPushButton hello("Hello world!");
    hello.resize(100, 30);

    hello.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

### Problem

When I inspect the produced html code in the browser, for the `hello(` part for example, I get:

```
 hello(
```

When I inspect the html code of the documentation however, which I believe is generated with the help of `QDoc` as well, for the same part I see:

```
<span class="pln"> hello</span>
```

I do not know why in my case the additional markup is missing.

### Question

How to setup QDoc so, that I can specify the rules of how each part of the code snippet should be marked up?

Comment: Can you post your working cpp-code? This doesn't look valid cpp to me: QPushButton hello("Hello world!");.resize(100, 30);

Comment: @Jens _This doesn't look valid cpp to me_ It does not look valid to me as well. As I've mentioned: I use the code from the documentation. This way I can make a side-by-side comparison of the results. It is also irrelevant. Even with `.resize(100, 30);` omitted, the result is still `" hello("`, without the tags.

Comment: @Jens Of course it is a valid cpp. Why it should not be?

Comment: @Jens, take a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/07-0-qdoc-commands-includingexternalcode.html#quotefile

Comment: It wasn't until October, 20.

Comment: @Jens, excuse me, but I really do not know what do you mean by that. I took this code snippet from the documentation and it has been there for years. Take a look for example at https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/tutorial1-01.html. This is from the archives for Qt 3.3.